# Toggling a single 'td' element from a column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I want to toggle single elements from the fourth column of a four column table. For example, if the element in the fifth row third column is clicked, then only the element in the fifth row fourth column should toggle.

My current code only toggles the fourth row fourth column element, regardless of which third column element is clicked.

```
$('td:nth-child(4),th:nth-child(4)').hide();

$('td:nth-child(3)').click(function() {
    $('td:nth-child(4),th:nth-child(4)').eq(4).toggle();
});
```

The fourth column 'th' element is also not toggling.

Comment: `$('td,th').eq(3).toggle();` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to somehow reference the clicked td. This is one way:

```
$('table').on('click', 'td:nth-child(3)', function () {

  $(this).next().toggle();
  // |     |
  // |     ^-- this selects the next sibling
  // |
  // ^-- `this` is a reference to the clicked td
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Find closest `tr` , select column 4, Then `toggle`:

```
$('td:nth-child(4),th:nth-child(4)').hide();

$('td:nth-child(3)').click(function() {
    var currentTdCol4 = 
    $(this).closest('tr').children('td:nth-child(4)');
    $(currentTdCol4).toggle();
    $('th:nth-child(4)').toggle();
});
```

Here is my Example: [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/z9yx8g7r/)